# Which scriptures mention Dhyana Mantras of the sixty-four Yoginis?

Tags: puranas, mantras, devi, tantra

In different places of India, there are temples of sixty-four Yoginis. Can anyone provide names of the scriptures where the detailed dhyana-mantras of these Yoginis and their functions are found? I think there are many scriptures as the Joginis differ from temple to temple.